# Avrdude can't connect to butterfly programmer

Tags: arduino-leonardo, avrdude, mac-os

I'm trying to upload my exported HEX file by avrdude using this command

`/Users/user_acc/Downloads/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/Users/user_acc/Downloads/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/cu.usbmodem1421 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/Users/user_acc/Documents/Arduino/at_command_A6/at_command_A6.ino.with_bootloader.leonardo.hex:i`

But instead of loading the file it's stuck on connecting to programmer.

Output: https://scr.hu/rYNzzm
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/74p37fGYPN/

The output from ArduinoIDE is exactly the same and it finds the programmer without the problem and loads the file.

`/private/var/folders/5h/7rxp3rmn5351zh6r8cxhz1sr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/5C2325EE-CF38-4140-8860-717C9DBAF376/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/private/var/folders/5h/7rxp3rmn5351zh6r8cxhz1sr0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/5C2325EE-CF38-4140-8860-717C9DBAF376/d/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -P/dev/cu.usbmodem124 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:/var/folders/5h/7rxp3rmn5351zh6r8cxhz1sr0000gn/T/arduino_build_78519/at_command_A6.ino.hex:i`

Output: https://scr.hu/M72NaV

Can somebody help me? :)

Comment: please update the second picture  so that it shows the command line (roll the screen down a bit)

Comment: @jsotola I added the whole output from Arduino in the paste.ubuntu.com link

Comment: @jsotola Thats the output from Arduino. What command line do you want to see?

Comment: go to "preferences" in the Arduino IDE .... check "show verbose output during" `upload` .... do an upload ..... the actual avrdude command line gets diplayed .... post that command line

Comment: @jsotola it was all the time in the output that I provided. Its in the question now as well. Dont mind the cu.usbmodem124. I changed the port during my attempts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a post of somebody with a similar issue. His solution fixed my issue!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46813157/avrdude-command-line-cant-connect-to-programmer-for-leonardo